# Kafka Scripts in bin Directory throws an error is "java.net.BindException: Address in use (Bind failed)"

Tags: networking, kubernetes, java, kafka

I have Deployed Kafka as a Stateful Set on k8's and the Service type is ClusterIP. It's Up & running.

However, when I'm logging into Kafka brokers (using kubectl exec -it pod_name -- bash) and go to the Kafka bin path & try to get some information about its state using one of the scripts in bin but unable to get the information

So it always throws this error i.e.;

`Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 9999; nested exception is:  java.net.BindException: Address in use (Bind failed)`

To avoiding that error I tried to change the port for JMX in the kafka Environment variable setup but still persists the Same problem i.e.; For suppose, changed the port from 9999 to 8989 then the same problem encounter on that port

So can anyone please help on this issue

Thanks!!

Comment: Can Anyone please help on this issue